# Want to disable & enable jenkins pipeline to achieve automation

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a idea where I need to send a mail if certain conditions are met to inform the Team. The condition may continue for 30 minutes or 1 hour. But I do not want to flood the mailbox with continuous mails. As we will be scheduling the job every minute, the mails will be sent every minute. So we are trying to disable the pipeline for specific time once the mail is sent and enable it again automatically.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to put the job on sleep, but as it was scheduled to build every minute, the new jobs were initiated every minute and mails were sent.

//This is scheduled to build every minute * * * * *

```
`pipeline{ 
 agent {
 stages {
 stage (check condition){
 when 
   // check conditions
   // if everything working fine - ok
   else
   // send email - this will be sent every minute. I want to avoid mailbox malfunction and just report the issue.
  }
  }
  }
  }`
```

Please help me with the solutions.

Comment: Look at using [email extension](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#plugin-content-triggers) and triggers combinations.

Comment: The main problem here seems to be that you are unable to maintain the state of the condition (when it last ran, when the email was sent). So maybe you can try to figure out a solution for that, such as using [envinject](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) to maintain the state as an environment variable or even writing the details to a file.

Comment: @IanW - I have checked the email extensions you mentioned but they do not work in my condition.

Comment: I think you have mis-phrased the problem. "trying to disable the pipeline for specific time once the mail is sent and enable it again automatically", Once you have self-disabled your pipeline, it's no longer running, so it can't be self re-enabled. It would need to be enabled via an external source (job or human). What you can do is continuously run your job (every minute) and play with whether it meets a condition to send an email. hence the suggest for Email Extension, which has lots of conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

I used alternative: Sending below URL in the mail.

To disable the pipeline -  $BUILDURL/disable to disable the pipeline.

The recipient will have to click on the link and disable the pipeline himself. This also means that the mail is acknowledged and has not gone unnoticed.

To enable the pipeline -  $BUILDURL/enable. Once the issue is fixed, the recipient can enable the pipeline..

Edit:

Adding pipeline sample for reference.

```
   pipeline{
      agent any

    stages {
       stage ('Checkout') {
            // checkout git repo
        }

       stage ('run job') {
          // script to run the job
       }
       stage('email') {
         when {
            expression(condition to be satisfied)
        }
        steps {
            send email 
            body - $Build_Url/disable to disable the job.
                   $Build_Url/enable to enable the job.
       }
    } 
}
```